# Nexus 3 How to create user with rights to upload ONLY to one repository

Tags: repository, admin, nexus

1. create repository R1
2. create Repository Admin Privileges Priv_1 (repository name = R1)
   Actions : create,add,browse
3. create Role Role1 with Priv_1
4. create adminR1 witj role Role1

but when i started Nexus under adminR1  i see only Welcome but not Browse, not Upload

p.s. it seems to me that only admin has permitions to upload something to ANY repository

Comment: I don't get why you are creating a privilege. Simply create a role `rw_access_to_yourrepo`. In that role add the following existing privilege: `nx-repository-view-<repotype>-<reponame>-*` (you can dissociate read, add, browse, edit and delete if needed with the atomic privileges entries). For the upload part, you also need to add the `nx-component-upload` privilege (you might later want to add that one on a shared role or even to the anonymous role depending on your requirements....). Now add that new role to your user. Done.

Comment: Thank u, this  help !